# What distribution still supports the 2.6.x kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, version

I'm trying to use a *Khepera III* robot. The documentation says I need a Linux OS with kernel 2.6.x. An Ubuntu 8 image was provided at the website. When I created a virtual machine with that image, I tried to install the packages I need for using Kheperra III but I couldn't. I tried also to install the updates but I couldn't since this version of Ubuntu is not supported anymore.

What Linux OS still supports kernel 2.6.x and allows me to install modern packages?

Comment: This is probably what virtual machines are for.

Comment: @devnull I didn't get your comment can you please explain more?

Comment: Instead of trying to modify _(downgrade)_ your kernel from 3.8 to 2.6.x which might not be trivial, try to run 2.6.x over a VM.

Comment: so you mean its ok to use outdated version of Linux with kernel 2.6.x as long as I'm using virtual machine?

Comment: "Can I change it and install kernel 2.6.x" -- probably.  You don't actually have to change it, you just have to install a 2.6 kernel and make that a boot option.  If it doesn't work, you re-boot with your original kernel and no harm done.  I can't absolutely guarantee, though, that *if it does work* there won't be some little issue that ends up causing you grief (I just doubt it very much), which is why the virtual machine option is safer (you are not exposing your host system).

Comment: @goldilocks I installed an ubuntu version with linux 2.6.x on a virtual machine but I wasn't able to install the packages I needed. How can I  overcome such problem?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question you should ask with details ;) P.s.: If you explain exactly why you *think* you need a 2.6.x kernel, someone might be able to discern whether you really do, which could save some time.

Comment: @goldilocks I rewrote the whole question to describe my situation

Comment: If this is just a platform for the cross-compiler from your other question, you *don't* need a specific kernel on the host system, but you probably will need to build (and install the sources for) a kernel *in the cross-compile environment* (this is a set of directories that includes, `bin/`, `lib/`, `include/`, etc.).  This is not so hard as the kernel doesn't require any libraries beyond what will already be in the toolchain. That kernel won't actually be run anywhere (unless you install it onto the robot), it's just used as a parallel to the one on the robot, for the cross-compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx is [uses the 2.6.x kernel](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.3/ubuntu-10.04-desktop-amd64.manifest) and the server edition is supported until 2015-04. You can download it here - http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.04/

For more on the differences between server editions and desktop editions of Ubuntu, see this [question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version).

The main issue seems to be that there is no desktop environment included in the default installation. As such there is no GUI installation, although what they give should be intuitive enough to use. You will get other packages installed which you usually get on a server too. Lucid is also old enough to have a server optimised kernel, I'm not sure what the exact differences are but they should me minor enough not to noticeably affect anything.

It should also be ok to install the desktop edition too, it can be downloaded here - http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.3/ (get a 10.04.4 download for more included updates). The repositories are the same for both anyway, it is just that 'server support' probably means that only the server relevant packages are updated. For example the server optimised kernel will probably get security updates while the desktop kernel won't.

Comment: Um, me neither. According to wikipedia the server edition doesn't install a graphical interface (and may only be a command line install). Generally it should be safe enough, it just gives different packages by default. Maybe a little more difficult to work with. I will investigate more and update.

Comment: The Ubuntu LTS versions are just regular Ubuntu with extended support (perhaps for a subset of packages, though). Grab a copy and try it out.

Comment: @vonbrand it is more about the issues with installing a server edition vs a desktop edition. Only the server edition is still supported for 10.04

Comment: @Graeme Does this implies that I won't be able to add the packages that I need?

Comment: @Alaa I think you will be ok - the full repository should still be intact, just that only certain packages will be updated.

Comment: The `tasksel` command is typically used to install a GUI on Ubuntu server versions. `tasksel` provides options to auto install package collections like desktops, LAMP, etc. Just don't install any of the "live" or "CD" options.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 6.5 ships with a 2.6.32 kernel. Not so sure though if it suits your needs to "install modern packages". It is supported until the end of 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head, while not the most cutting edge, RHEL/CentOS/Scientific Linux/ etc etc, Are quite a few years away from EOL and run a 2.6 kernel.